# What is the meaning of $\inf$?

Tags: optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I see it often in solution of some questions:

$$  \inf_x f(x,y) $$

as a next step of the solution usually I see something like this:

$$ \nabla_xf=0   $$

and then return $ x $ that satisfy it.

Comment: $\inf_t g(t)$ is the larger quantity $m$ such that $m \le g(t)$ for all $t$. For all $\varepsilon >0$, we can find $t_0$ such that $g(t_0) < m + \varepsilon$. Here the function depends on two parameters $x$ and $y$ but we only search the infimum with respect to $x$. Then $\textbf{inf}_xf(x,y)$ can be seen as a function of $y$, unless this infimum is $- \infty$ of course..

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the question? Are you asking what the subscript ${}_x$ means? The infimum in general? Or are you actually asking about the realtionship between a vanishing derivative at an extremum of that function?

Comment: I what to understand what is *inf* @hal4math

Comment: And what do you mean by "as a next step"? I think @nicomezi gives a good explanation.

Comment: @hal4math thank you, I updated the question

Comment: Okay, so these ideas are related but not in general. So, the notation of the infimum is a generalization of what you maybe know as the minimum. So every minimum that is attained is also an infimum. But sometimes functions or sets have not real minima but they have an infimum. For example the function $f(x) = x$ defined on $(0,1)$. Has no minimum in its domain, but the infimum would be zero.

Comment: As @hal4math was pointing out, the notation $\nabla_x f=0$ is consistent with finding a minimum, basically you are calculating the gradient vector, equating it to zero, and finding the $x$ at with the minimum is attained, but it's not the same when dealing with the infimum

Comment: The infimum means it is the smallest value for which there exists a sequence converging to that value

Answer (score 4):

The *infimum* of a set of numbers is the greatest lower bound.  It it similar to, but not always the same as, the *minimum*.

The problem with *minimum* is that it might not exist.  A standard example from early analysis courses is 
$$ 1+\frac{1}{n} \quad \forall n \in {\mathbb N}$$
which yields the set $\{2, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{4}{3}, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{6}{5}, \ldots \}$
What is the minimum of this set?  There is none: take any value you like for $n$ and someone else can take the value $n+1$ to find a smaller number than yours that is also in the set.

The *infimum* though does exist: it's $1$.  This is because no matter how large you take $n$ to be, $(1+1/n) > 1$, but you can get as close as you like to $1$.  If you want to be no more than $10^{-17}$ away from $1$ just take $n=10^{17}$ or larger and you're there.

*Infima* (or *infimums* if you prefer modern English plurals) arise in minimisation problems as your example suggests: if you have a compact set and a continuous function defined on it, then the infimum will also be the minimum.  Even if you don't, knowing what the infimum looks like bounds any possible solution to the minimisation problem and may allow you to describe a family of near-solutions to it.

Finally: in the real numbers infima don't need to exist: consider $1+n\cdot (-1)^n$  This has no infimum and will tend towards both positive and negative infinity.  However, in some circumstances (convex analysis especially) we extend the real numbers by adding $\pm \infty$ and then the infimum can be $-\infty$.  It can also be useful, when dealing with upper- and lower- semicontinuous functions to have them take $\pm \infty$ as values to indicate we are outside the range of interest.